# How do I monitor a port for traffic in Windows?

Tags: windows, performance, monitoring, traffic

I am trying to find a solution to monitor the traffic (in and out) through a specific port. It is not required to capture the packets, or do anyting else. What it does is to be a traffic listener to make sure there are messages sent to or received from this port every 10 minutes. It has to be running at the background all the time (like a daemon), and without significant performance impact. Based on my research, one choice is to use an existing tool to do that. There are a bunch of tools out there to monitor or sniff the traffic, such as wireshark. Well, seems most of them monitor the traffic passing through a interface, instead of a port, or they can't run as a daemon. Another choice to write a program to do this. [SharpPcap](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx) seems to be a good choice, but I still need to capture and analyze the packets to know whether such traffic exist. Could somebody suggest what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

SharpPcap handles packet capturing in the same manner as Wireshark, so you can set filters to limit the packet being captured to a specific port the same way in SharpPcap as you can in wireshark. Except, SharpPcap will be a much lighter weight option vs wireshark.

Download the SharpPcap [source tree](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/develop) and look at the Example05.SetFilter.

To narrow down the results so you capture only the packets you want to see you'll need to employ a few filters.

Pcap uses a common language across all applications that use it do specify the filters to set. Capture programs that use winpcap (windows) or libpcap (*nix) include, sharppcap, wireshark, pcap.net, winpcap, libpcap, tcpdump, etc... For a great resource on how to use pcap filters see [this link](http://www.lincoln.edu/math/rmyrick/ComputerNetworks/InetReference/56.htm).

Here are the filters you need:

- ether host *ehost*
- port *port*

Where the ehost is the MAC address of the computer sending/receiving the packets and the port is the port you want to monitor. So the full filter string would be.

```
SetFilter("ether host ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff and port 60");
```

The MAC and port here are for illustration purposes only, you'd obviously change them with the values that pertain to your specific setup.

This, used in the SetFilter example will simply print out a line of info with the time of when the packet was captured to the command line every time a packet is captured and meets the criteria if your filter.

If you want more detailed info about the packet, such as info from the headers or the packet's payload, you'll need to parse the incoming raw packet. Be sure to ask for help on the sourceforge project's forum if you need some tips on how to do this. The project developers are very active and always willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that will limit the impact your tool will have on performance is via an ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) Real-time Consumer (i.e. a tool that activates an ETW trace and reads it immediately instead of saving it to a file). [This MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EventTraceWatcher) is a great way to see how to do this via C# and it gives you some code to get started.